# Temporary values is not retained while navigate from one page to another page in the DataTable of Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working in the JSF2.2 with Primefaces 6.0 with Spring Data of JPA concepts. In PrimeFaces Datatable, I have entered a value in the input text. After entering I have to navigate from one page to another page in that Datatable. After navigated values vanished on the last visited page. But if I have saved those data into the database, those values can be retained in the last visited page. I think while clicking the paginator at the time it will maintain the DB session level values.

Comment: what have you tried to solve this yourself? add relevant code

Comment: you will need to provide some code what you are actually doing. Right now the question is really unclear and most likely impossible to answer.

Comment: You need to read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. And isn't the 'nature' of temporary that it is... well... temporary? Meaning not 'retained', so all seems normal here